# ArcMap trace the creation/moving/deletion events by windows user

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, editing, trace

I want to check whether there is a way to trace the creation, moving and deletion in the editing session by windows currently logged in user. What I only know now is how to trace the creation/moving/deletion events by database user and displayed in attribute table of the layers under the monitoring.

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this through [editor tracking](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m600000068000000):

> For file and personal geodatabases edited with ArcGIS for Desktop
>   clients, and ArcSDE geodatabases you connect to through operating
>   system authentication, the user name written is the operating system
>   [in your case Windows] login.

It sounds like you have previously been using this from the same Help page:

> For ArcSDE geodatabases you connect to through database
>   authentication, the user name is the name you use to connect to the
>   geodatabase.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo, yes I used the same help page. I am so stupid haven't realized it is based on the connection to the sde. Have tested on it and it works.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, another thing to confirm with you: by using the editor tracking, it seems only the latest action on an object can be displayed. Is there any means to record down all the actions? thanks.

Comment: @ppLily Whenever you have follow up questions to your original one our focussed Q&A format works best if you research/ask them separately. What you are asking is not something that I have done and my first thought is that you may need geodatabase versioning for that.